# network path is not found

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am getting a Error while accessing the share of one of the windows 2003 server. The error says "The network path was not found" even if the server is up and I am able to ping that also.

What could be wrong with that server ?

Comment: are you a network user of the server? do you have permission to access the network path? Can you ping the server both by name and IP Address? Does the server have a firewall enabled?

Comment: totally agree with your comment James.  Was about to suggest similar initial steps

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for you comments.Following are my findings -

1. i am not able to access network path
2. I am able to ping the server both by IPaddress and name
3. firewall is disable.

Please suggets

Answer (score 1):

Try to `telnet *server_name_or_ip* 445` in a dos prompt. If you get something else than a full black screen it probably means that either sharing is not setup correctly on the server or a firewall is blocking you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. While I am trying to use the process told by you..The error coming in cmd prompt is..Could not open connection to the host  , on port 445 : Connection failed.

Please suggest or share some links to trouble shoot this error

Comment: try to do telnet 127.0.0.1 445 on the server itself, if it's not working, I guess there is a setup problem on the server (and here i can't help more), if it's working it's probably a firewall problem

Comment: Yes telnet on that server itself is working fine. Is there anything else which I can check

Comment: Check for firewall on both computer and on the network path

Comment: firewall is also disabled